# Is \d not supported by grep's basic expressions?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

This does not generate any output. How come?

```
$ echo 'this 1 2 3' | grep '\d\+'
```

But these do:

```
$ echo 'this 1 2 3' | grep '\s\+'
this 1 2 3

$ echo 'this 1 2 3' | grep '\w\+'
this 1 2 3
```

Comment: None of those work for me (Solaris).

Comment: Me neither. (Cygwin) Did you mean to have `\+`? What does that mean?

Comment: yes, I am on Ubuntu 10.04 , using bash. For BRE in grep you have to escape some characters. Try "Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
" in man grep.

Comment: @FarmBoy: `+` in a regex means "one or more of the previous token". In this case it's escaped because that's the syntax required by `grep`'s default regex engine.

Comment: @Daenyth I can't believe that I've been able to `grep` for years without realizing that `+` needs to be escaped. Thanks.

Comment: @FarmBoy: `+` needs to be escaped if you're using `grep`; if you're using `egrep`, it doesn't.  `grep -E` is equivalent to `egrep` (at least for the GNU version).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514135/bash-regular-expression-cant-seem-to-match-any-of-s-s-d-d-w-w-etc/48898886#48898886 (the question is about Bash, but many of the observations readily transfer to `grep`, `sed`, Awk, etc).

Answer (score 253, accepted):

As specified in POSIX, `grep` uses [basic regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), but `\d` is part of a Perl-compatible regular expression ([PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#genericchartypes)).

If you are using GNU grep, you can use the `-P` option, to allow use of PCRE regular expressions. Otherwise you can use the POSIX-specified `[[:digit:]]` character class in place of `\d`.

```sh
echo 1 | grep -P '\d'
# output: 1
echo 1 | grep '[[:digit:]]'
# output: 1
```

Comment: BSD grep's -E mode includes \d. But GNU grep's -E mode does not. That's so glaring I'm shocked I'm just discovering it now.

Comment: > BSD grep's -E mode includes \d. But GNU grep's -E mode does not. That's so glaring I'm shocked I'm just discovering it now.

This just bit me on a git commit message validation script. I was very surprised \d was the culprit.

Answer (score 24):

Try this `$ echo 'this 1 2 3' | grep '[0-9]\+'`

Comment: maybe  "grep -E" option will help

Comment: @bortunac No, `\d` is not part of the Extended Regular Expression syntax either. (It will remove the need to backslash the `+` though.)