# Why doesn't this regex work for grep?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I'm trying to remove "Packet number 624 doesn't match" from a response so the obvious thing to try is

```
cat somefile.txt | grep -v "Packet number \d+ doesn't match"
```

If I remove the `-v`, just for testing, then it returns nothing. So maybe the command line is doing something with the `\d` or `+` first. So I have tried various combinations such as `\\d+ \\d\+ \\\\d+ \\\\d\+ [0-9]+ [0-9]\+`. Bingo!! That last one worked. Can someone explain what is going on here? If this is getting modified by the command line why does `echo "\d+"` still return `\d+`?

Comment: `\d` is extended grep so you need to use `grep -E`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is \d not supported by grep's basic expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901171/is-d-not-supported-by-greps-basic-expressions)

Comment: @Wolph that doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks, that works and answers that question. The question still remains as to why `[0-9]+` didn't work

Comment: Most probably you have to avoid cat command. Your command should be `grep -v "Packet number [0-9]\+ doesn't match" somefile.txt`

Comment: ^ Yes, swinging that cat around is unnecessary — `grep ... file` should work.

Comment: The cat is just for demonstrating the problem, the output actually comes from radsniff which we use to sniff radius traffic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, grep uses *basic regular expression* and `\d` is ([`PCRE`](http://pcre.org/)) syntax. It is not supported so you'll need to use ( `[0-9]` ) or ( `[[:digit:]]` ) instead, or use grep with option `-P`

**Why doesn't `[0-9]+` work?**

- In [BRE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), meta-characters like `+` lose their meaning and need to be escaped.

---

You can fix this by using one of the following:

```
grep -v "Packet number [0-9]\+ doesn't match"
```

OR

```
grep -v "Packet number [[:digit:]]\+ doesn't match"
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. This clears up something that has confused me for a long time which is why regex "sort of work" in some cases. I'd always assumed that non PCRE was basically the same with some subtle differences that I would likely never encounter.

Answer (score 1):

-v means inverse, any lines not matching pattern will be listed
-E is the right parameter
**[Correction]**
-E is the right parameter **WORKS IN Mac OS X**
-P is the right parameter, **TESTED IN Ubuntu**

try this

```
//in somefile.txt:
Packet number 100 doesn't match -E
Pck number 100 doesn't match -v
```

use `cat somefile.txt | grep -v "Packet number \d+ doesn't match"`
both lines appears
use `cat somefile.txt | grep -E "Packet number \d+ doesn't match"` in Mac OS X
use `cat somefile.txt | grep -P "Packet number \d+ doesn't match"` in Linux
only 
"Packet number 100 doesn't match -E"
appears, which is what you want.

Comment: I can confirm that the `-P` option works but the `-E` option returns nothing (or everything with `-v`)

Comment: @MikeKulls, when you use -v, `[0-9]+` won't work. try -E for `[0-9]+`

Comment: -v, in this case, nothing match the pattern, (\d does not work in default mode), so everything returns.

Comment: @MikeKulls just tested. see my correction in the answer.

Comment: More specifically, `-E` works in most BSDs and `-P` works in most linuxes

Comment: Even more specifically, `-E` works on any POSIX platform, whereas `-P` is a nonstandard extension.

Answer (score 0):

grep's re syntax didn't support notations like \d. There is a option to use Perl's syntax, try this,

```
cat somefile.txt | grep -v -P "Packet number \\d+ doesn't match"
```

Please note you need to escaspe the backslash.

Comment: A better fix is to use single quotes around your regex. Also, lose the [useless use of `cat`.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)